# How to avoid nested null checks

Tags: java

In java is there a way to avoid  having to nest null checks on each level of the call to ensure there were no nulls along the way which prevent the next call. Is there an elegant way to do this?

for example:

objOne.objTwo.objThree.objFour.objFive

```
if(objOne.objTwo!=null){
    if(objOne.objTwo.objThree!=null){
      if(objOne.objTwo.objThree.objFour!=null){
            ...
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know about class [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)?

Comment: @Abra, and how is `Optional` suppose to help in this context?

Comment: This [article](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/java8-optional.html) may be relevant.

Comment: @Abra, that doesn't help at all. `Optional` is **not** meant to replace every not null condition in Java. I guess you could create an `Optional.ofNullable()` out of every nested object. that would make the code much less comprehensible .

Comment: It is a matter of debate as to whether `Optional` helps or not.  But it is the only thing that could help ... apart from redesigning the data structure to eliminate the nulls as acceptable values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can collapse the nested if statements into one, using [short circuit logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). the first false condition will exit the if statement

```
if (objOne.objTwo != null && objOne.objTwo.objThree != null && objOne.objTwo.objThree.objFour != null) {
           ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invert them. (Replace `Object` with actual types.)

```
Object item1 = objOne.objTwo;
if (item1 == null)
   return; // continue if in a loop

Object item2 = item1.objThree;
if (item2 == null)
   return;

Object item3 = item2.objFour;
if (item3 == null)
   return;

// perform the action
```

This assumes there is no further action required beyond the end of your example. In that case you may have to extract a method or some other modification, but there is no such additional code given at the moment.

Comment: how is this qualify as inversion? the flow is not inverted

Comment: @SharonBenAsher depends on the outer context, but yes, this does the thing only if the conditions do not hold.